# What does systemd.volatile=state do when used along side of ro?

Tags: debian, kernel

Here is my `/boot/cmdline.txt` for context.

```
$ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=5838cc20-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8 fastboot fsck.mode=skip noswap ro systemd.volatile=state
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the system boot with the root filesystem as read-only and the `/var` mounted as a writable `tmpfs` RAM-disk. Basically a system should behave like a live Linux media without persistence.

Later parts of the start-up process might include remounting the root filesystem in read-write mode, or they might not.

Is this a RasPi or something similar? In that case, it might be to minimize the wear of the SD card by making the `/var` filesystem non-persistent, at the expense of reverting the state of `/var` back to what the read-only system image has, on every reboot.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I intend to use this config to use Raspberry Pi OS similarly to Tails (filesystem should be amnesic). Does this config work for this use case?

Comment: That's certainly a valid starting point for such a configuration, but depending on your requirements, you might need to tweak RasPi OS configuration further: you might symlink all things that need to be writeable-but-amnesic to under `/var`, or create one or more other `tmpfs` mounts where you need them (like `/home`).